# Routing webforms pages to a subfolder in a MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, routes, webforms

I have a legacy ASP.Net Webforms site that I'm converting to MVC. The existing webform pages are in the root of the application (http://localhost/legacypage.aspx), but I want them to be in a /legacy/ folder in the MVC app so I don't have to see them in the visual studio solution all the time. However I don't want the legacy pages to have to include the subdirectory in the URL (http://localhost/legacy/legacypage.aspx), I want them to continue to be reachable from the original Url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this in your global.asax:

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  }

  void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
    routes.MapPageRoute(null, "{pagename}.aspx", "~/legacy/{pagename}.aspx");
  }
```

You may need also need another call to MapPageRoute for the / route because this will only fix /default.aspx route.

Comment: will this approach include querystring parameters?

Comment: Yes - this will cover querystring parameters - just tested it.